# Entity Framework 'key not defined' when it clearly is?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this error in my Entity Framework code first application and I have no idea why because the key is clearly defined:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Image' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Here is my Image model.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Locabal.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Image : IIndexable<Uri>
    {
        [DataMember] public Uri UrlBase { get { return Id; } set { Id = value; } }
        [Key][DataMember] public Uri Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember] public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type `Uri` is not supported by EF. Use another appropriate data type.